# Storing timestamp in a SQL database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jodatime

I'm having an issue storing values into the sql database that I've created within Netbeans.

```
String bladeSerial;
String bladeType;
LocalTime startTime1;

private void startButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             


    Connection conn = null; 
    Statement st = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db01", "Administrator", "admin"); //run procedure getConnection to connect to the database - see below
     st = conn.createStatement(); //set up a statement st to enable you to send SQL statements to the database.
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


        System.out.println ("Successful Connection");


String query = "insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values ('+bladeSerial+', '+itemText+', '+(String.valueOf(startTime1))+')";
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    pstmt.setString(1, bladeSerial);
    pstmt.setString(2, bladeType);
    pstmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(startTime1));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // Exception handling
    Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The `startTime1` variable is saved in the format `HH:mm:ss.SSS`.  When running the code, I get the error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered ":" at line 1, column 65.

The error refers to the colon in the time, but I do not know how to get around this.

`SERIAL` is a `VARCHAR(5)`, `BLADETYPE` is a `VARCHAR(80)`, `STARTT1` is a `VARCHAR(12)`. All columns are in the `DATA` table.

Comment: *Never* build insert strings with string concatenation.

Comment: Looks like little Bobby Tables caught you. see http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: BTW The exact error is caused by not quoting the strings with single quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 4):

Use `PreparedStatement` instead, and set the parameters with the `set*` methods:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String query = "insert into DATA(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1) values (?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepateStatement(query)) {
    pstmt.setString(1, bladeSerial);
    pstmt.setString(2, bladeType);
    pstmt.setString(3, startTime1.format(formatter));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Exception handling
}
```

Comment: Great that you point out the use of `PreparedStatement`, but in general you shouldn't use a `String` to set a date, time or timestamp field. Use `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` or `java.sql.Timestamp` instead. Note that the specific case of this question (columns is a `VARCHAR(12)`) does warrant use of `setString`.

Comment: Thanks.  I have adjusted the code now with your edits, but am getting this error - java.sql.SQLException: The column position '1' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '0'.